# Webpack output structure changes, depending on files outside the entry

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, awesome-typescript-loader

My goal is to create a React component library with TypeScript. I have configured webpack to bundle my components and everything works as expected until I create a folder, that is outside the scope of the entry and which includes TypeScript files.

I have simplified the config as much as possible and I can still reproduce the problem.

**`webpack.config.js`**

```js
const path = require('path');

const jsConfig = {
  entry: './src/components/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    pathinfo: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    usedExports: true,
    sideEffects: false
  },
  mode: 'production'
}

const configuration = [jsConfig];
module.exports = configuration;
```

**`tsconfig.json`**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Here is the initial folder structure:

```
|-- node_modules
|-- src
|   `-- components
|       |-- Button
|       |   `-- Button.tsx // Example component
|       `-- index.ts // A file that exports all components
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
`-- webpack.config.js
```

When I run webpack, it creates a `dist` folder with the following structure:

```
-- dist
   |-- Alert
   |   `-- Alert.d.ts
   |-- index.d.ts
   `-- index.js
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve. However, I want to add, let's say, a helper function, and create a folder called  `helpers` in `src`. Then I add a simple `helper.ts` file and just add a function that logs something on the console. **I'm not exporting anything and I haven't invoked the helper function yet**. So if I run webpack now, the `dist` will look like this:

```
-- dist
   |-- components
   |   |-- Alert
   |   |   `-- Alert.d.ts
   |   `-- index.d.ts
   `-- index.js
```

I suppose there is something essential, that I'm missing in understanding webpack's workflow. Why does this `components` folder emerge in the build output? Notice that it also wraps the `index.d.ts` - definitely not what I'm going for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days on this issue, I think I've found the answer. I will describe my steps to fixing the problem:

1. **This is not a problem with webpack**.
   I realised that if the `helper` file is not with TypeScript extension, the build output does not change.
2. **There is no problem with the TypeScript loader**
   I replaced `awesome-typescript-loader` with `ts-loader` - the results were the same, the output folder structure changes depending on whether the `helper` is a TypeScript file or not. Moreover, I didn't find any configuration options for the loader, which would solve the issue.
3. **It's all about the configuration of TypeScript compiler**
   I had to pay more attention on the fact that both loaders I tried make use of the `tsconfig.json`. The [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details)  show that I can set the `files` or `include`/`exclude` properties of the configuration object, which will affect the end result of compilation. Here is the answer to the question why unused files are compiled:

> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler
>   defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in
>   the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded
>   using the "exclude" property.

One more thing to add, since I mentioned the location of `index.d.ts` in the output folder structure: My goal for `helper.ts` was to use it in the components, of course. Therefore I had to accept that with the current configuration, my output folder structure changes, because the helper file had be transpiled. This caused the type definition file to end in the `components` folder. I simply moved the `index.ts` (which exports the components) one level above - in `src` and updated the webpack entry file.

I hope this helps someone.